# Save a Pymol-movie in Python

Tags: python, pymol

How can I save a Pymol-movie in Python? All I could do is saving the frames as png-files [cmd.png()] and play the movie [cmd.mplay()].

Answer (score 0):

Relevant documentation is here: http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Making_Movies

In short, it looks like pymol does not itself offer a way to generate gif or movie files. Instead, they recommend using a third-party program to do the work of stitching together your png files into whichever format you want. This page I linked describes several options; here's just one, using `mencoder`, which comes packaged with the open source movie player [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/):

```
mencoder "mf://*.png" -mf type=png:fps=18 -ovc lavc -o output.avi
```

There are plenty of command line options you can specify to fiddle with your output file; read the doc I linked for more examples, read the `mencoder` docs, try some other options, find what works best for you.